# Accessing sObject fields

Tags: apex, sobject

I am writing apex class to handel multiple objects triggers. My question is:
Is here a way to get field of some kind of object assigned to sObject?

Exemple:

```
sObject kk = new Prouct(Name = 'Pro1');
kk.Name // this doesn;t work and i am looking for something n this place.
```

If i will find anything i will post here in mean time i ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [sObject class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) provides a list of methods.

The one you're looking for is: `get(fieldName)`

In your case, the code would be:

```
sObject kk = new Prouct(Name = 'Pro1');
String name = kk.get('Name');
```

Comment: thx for help... Now i get how lame it was :D Thx any way